# Как установить язык на карте HERE Maps?

Tags: android, карты

В приложении использую библиотеку от [HERE Maps](https://developer.here.com/). Там есть несколько методов установки языка для отображения на карте, но ни один не работает.

Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

```
map = mapFragment.getMap();
...
map.setMapDisplayLanguage(new Locale("ru"));
map.setMapSecondaryDisplayLanguage(new Locale("ru"));
```

Comment: Разработчик из Here ответил мне [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38033292/2742899)

Comment: Данный функционал заработал в последней версии sdk, но интересно то, что когда зум маленький, то надписи на русском, когда большой, то на транслите.